# How do I make sure child elements do not cover up inset shadow?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element with some child elements, and I'm trying to apply a inset box-shadow the child elements seem to be covering up the box-shadow, here is a jfiddle example:
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sightofnick/wdYpv/)

If you take away the `background-color` on the `optn` class you'll see the inset box shadow there, so my code **is** valid. So the questions is, how do I make it so the child elements appear under the box-shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wdYpv/3/

Move the background color to the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, find half-solution (works well if you don't have scroll inside).

You can position background in element under the shadow by placing it inside the :before or :after pseudo-class and setting it z-index: -1. It will do the background part.

But it will create new problem: To position :before element you will need to apply to .optn element "position: relative;" and if you apply "position: relative;" to it it will start to shows from under the rounded corners in Webkit browsers.

If you don't have scroll inside, you can fix it by rounding corners if the first and last .optn element, bit if you want to scroll this content then you unfortunately can't do so.

Anyway there is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qN99W/

Answer (score 0):

you can add padding like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/wdYpv/2/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your own goal correctly, you've already got the answer in your question. ;-) Remove the background-color from `optn` and add it to `optn-group` instead.

As you've already discovered, though, if you have a different background color for `optn` on hover or on active, it's still over top of that inset shadow. The easy and possibly lazy solution is to not modify background-color for those, but to use text-color and other effects (shifting by 1px down, for example). Or if you want the border-radius but for those special cases (hover, active) you can live without the shadow, just set border-radii appropriately.

Other than that, don't let the world brainwash you into thinking that just because we have great new tools in CSS that you can't use images anymore. What you REALLY want to do might still be more easily accomplished with images.

Look at the "pinking shears" effect on numerous webpages, and it's still done with one or more transparent PNGs artfully placed.