# css - box shadow covering all contained divs using absolute positioning

Tags: css

Here's a reference  http://cssdesk.com/rHWcz

What I'm trying to do is have one of the div's contained be under the box shadow. I think using absolute positioning might be giving me some problems, but it has to be absolute positioned.
It doesn't matter which one, but one of the box div's cannot lay on top of the box shadow.
Any ideas?

Comment: can u provide any code from what you've tried so far?

Comment: yes, the link at the very top of my post is what I'm doing

Comment: It is caused by the child divs background color.. If you set them to `RGBA` instead with a lower alpha, it would go through.. also.. try look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870499/how-do-i-make-sure-child-elements-do-not-cover-up-inset-shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems which you might want to resolve in order to fix this. The first is that your HTML is ambiguous / poorly formed:

```
<div class="out"><div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

My assumption is that what you really mean is:

```
<div class="out">
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

(You were missing a closing `</div>`)

With this fixed, the easiest solution is actually to pull the shadow *out* of the underlying tag (the `.out` `div`), and instead create the shadow as an *overlay*.

Example:

```
<div class="out">
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
 <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

With this done, you can easily place the `.left` and `.right` `<div>` elements where you want them, and then force the `.shadow` `div` to appear *on top*.

Consider the following CSS (I also normalized your CSS some to reduce repetition):

```
.out, .shadow {
  height: 600px; width: 600px;
}
.out {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  position: relative;
}
.shadow {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px ;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
  left: 0; 
}
.right {
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}
```

Because the `.shadow` `div` appears *last*, you don't need any special `z-order` in order to get it to appear on-top.

[Here is a working cssdesk](http://cssdesk.com/JQpgs) to demonstrate it in-action.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments - the original question actually asks for only one of the two boxes to appear *under* the `box-shadow`. If you want one of them to appear *above* it, simply move that box's HTML tag so that it appears *after* the `.shadow` `<div>`, like this:

```
<div class="out">
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="shadow"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

This will cause the `.right` box (the red one) to appear *above* the shadow, rather than below - without the need for any `z-index` nastiness.

I have updated the cssdesk example to show this version instead.

Comment: bingo, that's what i was going for. and yes, i forgot to close the div, thanks for noticing. keen eye, sir! nice job on everything, i have a better understanding of things now!

Comment: actually this isn't quite what I wanted, but it will work. I only wanted to have one of the boxes under the drop shadow, it does say that in my question. I guess I can just z-index it up for now...

Comment: All you need to do is move one of the boxes *after* the `.shadow`

Comment: awesome. i was thinking it was something like that. The original missing closing div actually was supposed to go on the very end of everything. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your cssdesk link is defunct. Can you include it as a snippet here instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
.left, .right {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

You must remove the background color to `.out`, though. There is no way to place an element between anothers box shadow and background.

Comment: what about somehow using multiple backgrounds within the same div?

Comment: You'd run into a problem with interacting with content that has a z-index:-1. That effectively puts it below/behind the body.

Comment: z-index: -1 isn't good solution if user2118228 add z-index to parent element, ofcourse if he have to add.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create another element the height and width of the container and position it to the top left with absolute.

You can see an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MAckM/12/)

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

You'd run into a problem with not being able to click on any content below the positioned element with the box-shadow. A way around this would be to hide it when the user hovers.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="out"></div>  
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:600px
}
.out {
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px ;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}  
.left {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;left:0; bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.right {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:red;right:0; bottom:0;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:4;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sqJyw/4/
```

**EXPLANATION**

I add div which wrapped your content, manipulate z-index of Your samll div to show or hide them.

Comment: Nice solution, though your CSS is a little repetitive and it changes the parent/child relationship, which somewhat defeats the purpose of showing the box shadow "over the divs contained"

Comment: for this one the green box (left) isn't showing up...i'm using firefox